# PHP gd library crop white background to transparent png

Tags: php, gd

i'm trying to work a little bit with images and php. Please have a look at the following script.

```
<?php

//testcall prepare.php?img=https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/515SENGgRnL.jpg&h=200&n=test.png

$file=$_GET["img"];
$height=$_GET["h"];
$name=$_GET["n"];



function transparent($picture) 
{
    $img_w = imagesx($picture);
    $img_h = imagesy($picture);

    $newPicture = imagecreatetruecolor( $img_w, $img_h );
    imagesavealpha( $newPicture, true );
    $rgb = imagecolorallocatealpha( $newPicture, 0, 0, 0, 127 );
    imagefill( $newPicture, 0, 0, $rgb );

    $color = imagecolorat( $picture, $img_w-1, 1);

    for( $x = 0; $x < $img_w; $x++ ) {
        for( $y = 0; $y < $img_h; $y++ ) {
            $c = imagecolorat( $picture, $x, $y );
            if($color!=$c){         
                imagesetpixel( $newPicture, $x, $y,    $c);             
            }           
        }
    }
    echo "habs transparent gemacht! <br> ";
    return $newPicture; 
}

function resize($img,$w,$name){
    $ratio = imagesx($img)/imagesy($img); 
    if( $ratio > 1) {
        $width = $w;
        $height = $w/$ratio;
    }
    else {
        $width = $w*$ratio;
        $height = $w;
    }
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    imagesavealpha($dst, true);
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($dst, 0, 0, $color);
    imagecopyresampled($dst,$img,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,imagesx($img),imagesy($img));
    imagepng($dst, "test.png"); 

};

function crop($img){
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
    $b_top = 0;
    $b_btm = 0;
    $b_lft = 0;
    $b_rt = 0;
    for(; $b_top < imagesy($img); ++$b_top) {
      for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $b_top) != 0xFFFFFF) {
           break 2;
        }
      }
    }
    for(; $b_btm < imagesy($img); ++$b_btm) {
      for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $x, imagesy($img) - $b_btm-1) != 0xFFFFFF) {
           break 2;
        }
      }
    }
    for(; $b_lft < imagesx($img); ++$b_lft) {
      for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $b_lft, $y) != 0xFFFFFF) {
           break 2; 
        }
      }
    }
    for(; $b_rt < imagesx($img); ++$b_rt) {
      for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, imagesx($img) - $b_rt-1, $y) != 0xFFFFFF) {
           break 2; 
        }
      }
    }
    $newimg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($img)-($b_lft+$b_rt), imagesy($img)-($b_top+$b_btm));
    imagecopy($newimg, $img, 0, 0, $b_lft, $b_top, imagesx($newimg), imagesy($newimg));
    return $newimg;
};

$pic_cropped=crop($file);
$pic_transparent=transparent($pic_cropped);
$pic_resized=resize($pic_transparent,$height,$name);
?>
```

Input is a jpg, height and output name. First function crop crops the white space on all sides. Then set the white background color to transparent and the resize the whole pic to the height. So far the script is running fine on my Mac with MAMP. I tried to run on raspberry pi and on Ubuntu Linux in hosted area. The out on my mac is perfect: https://ibb.co/fNeFzk

Output on Raspberry and hosted Linux is bad: https://ibb.co/kdbCek

Hope you can see the difference. Same PHP Version, Same Apache Version. Any Ideas how to solve that?